# Windows 7 reinstall MS shadow copy provider (swprv) while missing it's registry, no restore points and regsvr32 commands is not a way

Tags: windows, windows-7, services, system-restore, windows-backup

I have a specific problem with Win 7 (along with thousands other users). My Windows 64 bit Service Pack 1 restore system doesn't work, I can't create a restore point in Windows Defence (Error 0x81000203) or create disk archive in Archivation and Restore section (Error 0x807800A1 (Shadow copy service Error 0x80042302)).

I have sufficient space and did nothing, but didn't check backup long. As I understand some "Desktop cleaner", or "System helper utility" or antivirus program deleted the VSS service by error or for user-dependence purposes, but there is not installed any now and antivirus uninstall doesn't help. I have checked event viewer for the default VSS provider and got an Error in creation of COM class VSS provider CLSID {65ee1dba-8ff4-4a58-ac1c-3470ee2f376a} SW_PROV 0x80070424 service not installed error :
https://pastebin.com/0ZEDJERd

I have checked shadow copy service and restarted it (no effect), checked this solution https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/0x80070715-for-swprvdll-troubleshooting-for/74ea72ed-8c78-4078-9b80-c93b18fe7936 with regsvr32 commands it works for first Dll's but on swprv.dll it shows 0x80070715 error (couldn't call DllRegister)

Also I have checked group policies - where isn't any and registry - HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Providers{b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}\CLSID branch is on place but there isn't any section called HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\swprv

Dlls are not missing so sfc /scannow or Dism will not take effect

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [found](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/backup-fails-event-12292-11) an [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/ru-RU/e1512d8c-a40b-48ef-806b-e94809822575/error-when-trying-to-create-a-system-image?forum=w7itprosecurity):
If swprv not in registry, then regsvr32 commands are not enough - you should [delete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-delete) and [create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create) swprv service.

All commands have been run in CMD as administrator

Firstly stop vss and swprv services:

```
net stop vss
net stop swprv
```

Attention! **uninstalling** swprv service

```
sc delete swprv
```

After that you need to reregister all DLLs and install service once more

**Installing** for english-language OS users (IDK literal DisplayName in services.msc in english system but also should work if doesn't collide with existing):

```
sc create swprv binPath= C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe DisplayName= "Microsoft Volume Shadow Copy Service software provider" type= own start= demand error= normal depend= rpcss obj= LocalSystem
```

*Optional*: Reregistering DLLs (this is necessary if after installation of swprv and registry editing (next step) you cannot run it with `net start`)

```
cd /d C:\Windows\system32
regsvr32 /s ole32.dll
regsvr32 /s oleaut32.dll
regsvr32 /s vss_ps.dll
vssvc /register
regsvr32 /s /i swprv.dll
regsvr32 /s /i eventcls.dll
regsvr32 /s es.dll
regsvr32 /s stdprov.dll
regsvr32 /s vssui.dll
regsvr32 /s msxml.dll
regsvr32 /s msxml3.dll
regsvr32 /s msxml4.dll
vssvc /register
```

**Editing registry** for correct service booting after installation (win+r regedit):

In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\swprv (that should create after sc command) change ImagePath from

```
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
```

to

```
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k swprv
```

and in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\swprv create `Parameters` section (with right-click). In that branch add expandable string parameter (REG_EXPAND_SZ type) `ServiceDll`

Change it's value to

```
%Systemroot%\System32\swprv.dll
```

If everything is correct

```
net start vss
net start swprv
```

Should run services and in My Computer -> Defence section you can create new restore points.

If installing service **WITH** registry editing and/without **DLL reregister** doesn't work in forward or reverse order, next step for you is recompiling **[DCOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/atl/dcomcnfg?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)** VSS component that's not a scope of this instruction.

Reinstalling command for russian-language OS users:

```
sc create swprv binPath= C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe DisplayName= "Программный поставщик теневого копирования (Microsoft)" type= own start= demand error= normal depend= rpcss obj= LocalSystem
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).